# How to hide/show thumb drawable in a SeekBar

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a SeekBar with a custom drawable for the Thumb, and I would like to be able to show/hide it based on another control I have.

I have tried loading the drawable from resources, and then using SeekBar.setThumb() with the drawable, or null.

That hides it (the set to null), but I can never get it back.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best way to do this is to set the drawable for the thumb from XML (as I was doing all along) and then when you want to hide/show the Thumb drawable, just manipulate it's alpha value:

```
// Hide the thumb drawable if the SeekBar is disabled
if (enabled) {
    seekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(255);
} else {
    seekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
}
```

Edit:

If thumb appearing white after setting alpha to zero, try adding

```
<SeekBar
    ....
    android:splitTrack="false" 
/>
```

Comment: Good answer! But be careful - getThumb() is for Jelly Bean(16)+ devices. For previous versions use something like: setThumb(bHide ? getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent) : getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.player_seekbar_handle));

Comment: And for `getDrawable(int)` is deprecated, you might want to write something like `setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, bHide ? R.color.transparent : R.drawable.player_seekbar_handle));`

Comment: For API level more than 21 you should have a look at this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27540406)

Comment: For me this leaves a white gap over the background drawable. Seems like the thumb has a non transparent container view or?

Comment: U can  try this :android:splitTrack="false",and for detail :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background

Answer (score 10):

Hide your  thumb in a SeekBar via xml

```
 android:thumbTint="@color/transparent"
```

for Example

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:thumb="@color/gray"
android:thumbTint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Do you know on what API level that was introduced and how far back it goes in Android SDK versions?

Comment: This was introduced in API 21

Comment: if you are gonna use this approach the you also need to add  android:splitTrack="false".

Answer (score 5):

**The easiest & simplest way to do it is
just add this line in your Seekbar view in its xml**

```
android:thumb="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: if you are gonna use this approach the you also need to add android:splitTrack="false".

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the seekbar thumb by setting arbitrarily large thumb offset value, which will move the thumb out of view. For example,

```
mySeekBar.setThumbOffset(10000);    // moves the thumb out of view (to left)
```

To show the thumb again, set the offset to zero or other conventional value:

```
mySeekBar.setThumbOffset(0);        // moves the thumb back to view
```

This approach works in all API levels.

Comment: I *think* this seems hacky......

If the seekbar's max is > 10000, the thumb will begin to show when the seekbar's progress becomes > 10000.  It will also begin to appear at the beginning of the seekbar and will seem odd to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Hide your thumb in a SeekBar via xml

```
   android:thumb="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this two line of code into your seekbar xml

android:thumbTint="#00D1CEB0"

android:splitTrack="false"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).