# How to remove the default indicator icon of a seekbar [android] which has been set a custom progress drawable

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Please find the below screenshot of a custom seekbar I am trying to achieve.
[image]

I am very much close in building the seekbar as shown above (without the images below the seekbar). Below is the screenshot of what I have done.

[image]

**Problem:**

As you can see in the second screenshot, there is an icon after the progress indicator bar in the seekbar. I have been trying to get rid of that but apparently not successful in doing that. Any suggestions/ideas on how to remove that icon would be of great help. Thanks.

**SeekBar Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.application.todo.activityTransition.activities.SeekBarActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/painLevelText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/painLevelText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/radIoGroupLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/painLevelText"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/seekBarRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/defaultSelection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radIoGroupLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/seekbar_layout_background">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="5"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seek_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarProgressValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom Drawable file used for seekbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="12dp"
                android:height="12dp" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />

            <solid android:color="#FF8D1E" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#FF8D1E"
                android:endColor="#FF971F"
                android:startColor="#FF971F" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**Please find my answer under answer section**

Comment: check  url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855815/how-to-hide-show-thumb-drawable-in-a-seekbar

Comment: Please post your activity code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855815/how-to-hide-show-thumb-drawable-in-a-seekbar) was helpful in achieving the desired result. But I found an issue while using the below line of code

```
seekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
```

It does remove the thumb at the end but the progress indicator is chopped when we select "10" from the radiogroup. Below is the related image.

[image]

But when I used this XML tag for seekbar in my layout, it was working as expected.

```
android:thumb="@null"
```

**Image**

[image]

Not sure if that was the right approach but it did the trick.

Comment: Hi Itapu, Can you post your complete code, the class files, how you have acheived this. I'm also having a same requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this line in your Seekbar xml code..

```
          android:thumbTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
android:splitTrack="false"
seekbar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `SeekBar` is the correct implementation for your use case. Try using a `ProgressBar` instead, then you don't have to worry about the thumb.

Comment: Hey Kent, Thanks for your time in posting a reply. Can you suggest any links/references where I can find info on getting started with progress bar implementation?

Comment: Simply replace SeekBar with ProgressBar in your XML layout and your activity/fragment and you should be fine.

Comment: It isn't working. I have changed seekbar to progressbar (in XML and also related code in activity). The progress bar isnt visible. Below is the change made in xml.


<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:max="10"
            android:progress="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seek_bar" />