# Android Seekbar dot want disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a project to build android application use seekbar. I wanna the dot seekbar disapper is posible? if possible how to make the dot disappear. like this http://prntscr.com/bwgaok

Comment: do you want to add some custom image or you want to disappear only ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide/show thumb drawable in a SeekBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855815/how-to-hide-show-thumb-drawable-in-a-seekbar)

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this one and it works for me

Use this following library for circular seekbar

https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar

and give `app:pointer_radius="0dp"`

It will work better

Comment: which library you used for your seekbar, or you used this library ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `seekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);` ?

If you wish to make the seekBar "unclickable" use `seekBar.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: Instead of "get error" post the error so we can help you out.

Comment: how to make seekbar can't be clickable?

Comment: @TempatBerbagiVideo I edited my question to answer yours.