# Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)

Tags: android, seekbar, android-slider

I would like to have this seekbar in my Android project :
[image]

This is my seekbar :

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar_luminosite"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/seekbar_height"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="15dp"
        android:progress="@integer/luminosite_defaut"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" />
```

This is my custom_thumb.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/colorDekraOrange"
        android:startColor="@color/colorDekraOrange" />

    <size
        android:height="35dp"
        android:width="35dp" />

</shape>
```

This is my custom_seekbar.xml :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@color/colorDekraYellow" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is my seekbar.png (background) :

[image]

And this is the result :
[image]

No shadow and no rounded borders in the bar...

I really not understand how I can do.

Comment: what are those blue color lines in your required output image ?

Comment: Have you tried `android:minHeight`

`android:maxHeight`

Comment: use `android:progressDrawable`

Comment: that's no working

Comment: A side note: If you set the SeekBar's `android:minHeight` and `android:maxHeight` to the same large value, it will increase the 'hit' area of the thumb, to make it much easier to grab and move (Set both values to avoid bugs on Android 4.4). Android 6/7 has a default SeekBar height which is very small, making it hard to click on.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

- First at all, use `android:splitTrack="false"` for the transparency problem of your thumb.
- For the *seekbar.png*, you have to use a **9 patch**. It would be good for the rounded border and the shadow of your image.

Comment: I worked on this some the 1st time the bounty was offered (with no luck).  Adding only 'splitTrack' made mine work.  Good answer.

Answer (score 150):

All done in `XML` (no `.png` images). The clever bit is **`border_shadow.xml`**.

All about the `vectors` these days...

Screenshot:

[image: seekbar]
This is your `SeekBar` (`res/layout/???.xml`):

### SeekBar

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar_luminosite"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:progress="@integer/luminosite_defaut"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"/>
```

Let's make it *stylish* (so you can easily customize it later):

### style

`res/drawable/seekbar_style.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@android:id/background" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/border_shadow" >
    </item>

    <item 
        android:id="@android:id/progress" > 
        <clip 
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### thumb

res/drawable/custom_thumb.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorDekraOrange"/>
            <size
                android:width="35dp"
                android:height="35dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>   
</layer-list>
```

### progress

`res/drawable/seekbar_progress.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/progressshape" >
        <clip>
            <shape 
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <size android:height="5dp"/>
                <corners 
                    android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorDekraYellow"/>        
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### shadow

`res/drawable/border_shadow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">       
    <item>      
        <shape> 
            <corners 
                android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:startColor="#33000000"
                android:centerColor="#11000000"
                android:endColor="#11000000"
                android:centerY="0.2"
                android:type="linear"
            />          
        </shape> 
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: this answer only needs `android:splitTrack="false"` to be added to the seek bar, so the thumb does not show white corners when moving. But thank you very very much!

Comment: @thechaoticpanda yes (android:splitTrack="false") but Jéwôm' (accepted) answered that, I steal no one's thunder, just hope to add to the community (hopeful with a unique perspective, with good code/rationality)...Maybe I will put in an`XML` comment section. Might be interesting to see how Android does it (shadow)...

Comment: If you are going with this, don't forget to add android:minHeight="11dp"
android:maxHeight="11dp", otherwise you will face "seekbar-bar-thumb-centering-issues"

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, clearly he does not understand scalability

Answer (score 22):

> No shadow and no rounded borders in the bar

You are using an image so the easiest solution is row your boat with the flow,

You cannot give heights manually,yes you can but make sure it gets enough space to show your full image view there

- easiest way is use  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `SeekBar`
- To get more clear rounded borders you can easily use the same image that you have used with another color.

I am no good with Photoshop but I managed to edit a background one for a test

[image: seekbar_brown] 
<sub>seekbar_brown_to_show_progress.png</sub>

```
<SeekBar
    android:splitTrack="false"   // for unwanted white space in thumb
    android:id="@+id/seekBar_luminosite"
    android:layout_width="250dp"   // use your own size
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:minWidth="15dp"
    android:maxHeight="15dp"
    android:maxWidth="15dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" />
```

**custom_seekbar_progress.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_brown_to_show_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**custom_thumb.xml** is same as yours

Finally `android:splitTrack="false"` will remove the unwanted white space in your thumb

Let's have a look at the output :

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Android custom SeekBar - custom track or progress, shape, size, background and thumb and for other seekbar customization see http://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples

**Custom Track drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="#ffd600">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <size android:height="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffd600" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <selector>
                <item android:state_enabled="false"
                    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
                <item>
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
                        android:tint="#f50057">
                        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
                        <size android:height="30dp" />
                        <solid android:color="#f50057" />
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </selector>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Custom thumb drawable**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:tint="#ad1457">
    <solid
        android:color="#ad1457" />
    <size
        android:width="32dp"
        android:height="32dp" />
</shape>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Please explain the relevance of `<Scale>` because the code won't work properly without that tag. :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the official [**`Slider`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) in the Material Components Library.

Use the **`app:trackHeight="xxdp"`** (default value is `4dp`) to change the height of the track bar.

Also use these attributes to customize the colors:

- `app:activeTrackColor`: the active track color
- `app:inactiveTrackColor`: the inactive track color
- `app:thumbColor`: to fill the thumb

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:activeTrackColor="#ffd400"
        app:inactiveTrackColor="#e7e7e7"
        app:thumbColor="#ffb300"
        app:trackHeight="12dp"
        .../>
```

[image]

It requires the version **1.2.0** of the library.

Comment: Can you help how to add this material lib into my Kotlin project?

Comment: @AnasReza Just add the dependency in your build.gradle. Here all the [info](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Comment: Is it possible to customize thumb icon?

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov Currently you can customize these attributes: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md#thumb-attributes

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it would be great if you add customisation for thumb icon with thumb elevation. The SeekBar hasn't thumbElevation and the Slider hasn't custom thum.

Answer (score 8):

At first courtesy goes to **@Charuka** .

### DO

You can use **`android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"`** instead of **`android:background="@drawable/seekbar"`** .

**[progressDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)** used for the progress mode.

You should try with

**[android:minHeight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight)**

> Defines the minimum height of the view. It is not guaranteed the view
>   will be able to achieve this minimum height (for example, if its
>   parent layout constrains it with less available height).

**[android:minWidth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minWidth)**

> Defines the minimum width of the view. It is not guaranteed the view
>   will be able to achieve this minimum width (for example, if its parent
>   layout constrains it with less available width)

```
    android:minHeight="25p"
    android:maxHeight="25dp"
```

**FYI:**

Using **android:minHeight and android:maxHeight** is not good solutions .Need to rectify your **Custom Seekbar (From Class Level)** .

Comment: @Jewom take a look here http://www.android-examples.com/create-custom-seekbar-in-android-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 7):

**android:minHeight android:maxHeight** is important for that.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="2dp"
    android:minHeight="2dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_bg"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"/>
```

**seekbar_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ECF0F1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#C6CACE" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#16BC5C" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**seekbar_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#16BC5C" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#16BC5C" />
    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use tints ;)

```
<SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="15dp"
        android:progress="20"
        android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

use the color you need in thumbTint and progressTint.
It is much faster! :)

Edit ofc you can use in combination with `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"`

Comment: Thanks but using tint don't change the problem. And I need to change the size of the thumb.

Comment: This require min API level 21.

Answer (score 4):

For future readers!

Starting from [material-components-android 1.2.0-alpha01](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0-alpha01), you can use new `slider` component

ex:

Modify `thumbSize`, `thumbColor`, `trackColor` accordingly.

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:valueFrom="20f"
        android:valueTo="70f"
        android:stepSize="10"
        app:thumbRadius="20dp"
        app:thumbColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:trackColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
```

Note:
  Track corners are not round.

Answer (score 1):

## Very simple way to change color of bar and thumb:

```
SeekBar slider;
ColorStateList sl = ColorStateList.valueOf( Color.YELLOW );
slider.setThumbTintList(sl);
slider.setProgressTintList(sl);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try progress bar instead of seek bar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    />
```