# How to change the color of seekbar's thin line and its circle in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I just want to change the color of seekbar's thin line and Its circle shaped cursor. Also, change color on progress. I mean, two colors i.e default (white) and progressed (black). I'm new to Xamarin and new to Android.

Comment: You need to do a custom seekbar, see here [Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)