# Make Android Seekbar line thinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, mobile

Please help me to create a seek bar with thinner line. Here is the code

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sb_zoom_size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:max="200"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:progress="100"
        app:tickMark="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tickMarkTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tickMarkTintMode="multiply"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size/thickness of your seek-bar just by using these two attributes of seekbar: 
`android:minHeight="20dp"` and `android:maxHeight="20dp"`

For example,in your case :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sb_zoom_size"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:max="200"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:tickMark="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tickMarkTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tickMarkTintMode="multiply" />
```

If you need a more customizable SeekBar then you'll need to use drawable and you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background) post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this attributes in `AppCompatSeekBar`

```
android:minHeight="2dip"
android:maxHeight="2dip"
```