# Creation of custom components or objects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, customization

hope you´re ok.

So, i was wondering about this, because, i can´t find a complete and/or good information about it.

Is the creation of custom components impossible in android studio?(let´s say, a `Button` with triangle shape; circular `SeekBar`; vertical `Seekbar`, line connected dots with touch capabilities; etc).
And, if it is, how can i achieve this? Using some other software?
I´ve found some libraries of different `SeekBar` shapes (circular, Arc) but i don´t want to use a library, i want to make it myself. Of course, is not out of arrogance, i´m just so curious and i think this will teach me some good an useful stuff for future apps. Can you guys give me like a guide or a list of things i should learn so i can manage to do this? Or maybe you guys know about a page that show this?

if you are wondering why do i want to do this, i´m working on an app that will look so much better with a custom component and , also, will work smothly, i hope.

Thank you in advance to everyone. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Without using another library we can customize controls in android. Please refer the links below
Customizing Buttons
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-buttons-in-android-using-android-studio/
Customizing Seek bar
[Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)

just google it, you will get many tutorials regarding this

Comment: Thanks for taking yout time to answer, but, as i post it, i was not able to find the information i wanted on google ( i´ve been searching for quite a while now), or, consider useful for what i want to do.I´ll visit the links tho and check the answer as correct if this works for me.