# customise seekbar and show seekbar thumb based on focussed state

Tags: android, seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I want to customise my seekbar as below. And also would want to show the thumb only when the seekbar has focus i.e when user is dragging the seekbar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just hide the thumb in `onStopTrackingTouch()` and make it visible in `onStartTrackingTouch()`.

```java
final SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
//Hide the seekbar's thumb.
seekbar.getThumb().setAlpha(0);
final Handler seekBarHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekbar, final int progress, final boolean feomUser)
    {
         //Do something...
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekbar)
    {
        seekBarHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        seekbar.getThumb().setAlpha(255);
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekbar)
    {
        //Hide the thumb if not focus for a second.
        seekBarHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                seekbar.getThumb().setAlpha(0);
            }
        }, 1000L); //Delay
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Any inputs on how I can customise seekbar like in the above image.

Comment: Look a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background). If you're still have a problem, don't hesitate to ask a new question.