# How to hide/show thumb in a SeekBar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm trying to hide the thumb of seekBar by default and show it if you touch the seekbar for the first time, but I can't make the thumb invisible.
I tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855816/5479029 but then I can see a white gap instead of the thumb
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145751/5479029 but then the thumb is placed in a wrong place when I try to make it visible again and use this `mySeekBar.setThumbOffset(0);`
- `seekbar.getThumb.setVisible(false, false)` - it doesn't work as well

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:(To remove gap)

```
seekbar.setSplitTrack(false);
seekbar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
```

Or, You can add following In the seekbar's XML layout.

```
android:splitTrack="false"
```

Comment: Now I see that a white gap was visible on Android 5.0 and it's not visible on Android 4.4 so it's a good solution thanks!